# Trouble mounting SquashFS filesystem from TP-Link Deco M5 router firmware

Tags: filesystems, mount, binary-files, reverse-engineer

### Question

I am new to reverse engineering and trying to retrieve the file system of a TP-Link Deco M5 router from its firmware. I have successfully extracted the SquashFS filesystem from the firmware using `binwalk`, and then attempted to mount it using the `mount` command, but I encountered an issue.

### Firmware Information

- Firmware URL: [Deco_M5_1.6.1_220818.zip](https://static.tp-link.com/upload/firmware/2022/202209/20220921/Deco_M5_1.6.1_220818.zip)
- Extracted binary file: `M5 1.0_en_1.6.1 Build 20220818 Rel. 36456_US_EU_JP_AU_CA_TW_B4_ID_UK_SW_EG_up.bin`
- Offset of SquashFS filesystem: `3586263`

### Extraction Process

1. Used `binwalk` to identify the SquashFS filesystem at decimal offset `3586263`.
2. Used `dd` to extract the filesystem: `dd if=M5\ 1.0_en_1.6.1\ Build\ 20220818\ Rel.\ 36456_US_EU_JP_AU_CA_TW_B4_ID_UK_SW_EG_up.bin skip=3586263 bs=1 of=filesystem.squashfs`

### Mounting Attempt

1. Created a directory: `mkdir mount_point`
2. Attempted to mount the SquashFS filesystem: `sudo mount -t squashfs -o loop filesystem.squashfs mount_point`

### Error Encountered

```
mount: /home/xyz/Downloads/Deco_M5_1.6.1_220818/mount_point: can't read superblock on /dev/loop0.
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

### Question

Can someone help me understand and resolve the issue I am facing with mounting the SquashFS filesystem? What could be causing the "can't read superblock" error, and how can I successfully mount the filesystem?

Thank you in advance for any guidance or assistance!